# how can i replicate the cluster sprinkles on this cupcake model

Tags: modeling

im modelling the cupcake below but i dont know how to replicate the cluster of sprinkles on the top.
[image][image]
i have had no problems replicating the smaller granules by using a particles system but i dont know how else to make it other than hand modelling the large cluster that heaps at the top which would take ages as i would have to duplicate and rotate it so it looks in a natural fashion.